# Is it better to use ajax pager or plain post back?

Tags: ajax, performance, seo, postback

I'm creating a pager for grid data. Basically, I can do it in two ways: when user clicks on a page number, load grid data by using ajax call, or, post back to server (GET or POST) and use query string parameters (or POST variables) to know which page to display. With both methods, sorting of grid items must be persisted.

What is better considering performance and SEO and why?

**-- UPDATE --**

I need pros and cons for both approaches. I know this is somewhat discussion rather than question, but I need your experiences.

Also, when using ajax, it is not only SEO that I'm wondering about. Will browser's back button behave as expected?

Comment: If want your data to be indexed by search engines - you need to provide a way to select anything using only GET

Comment: Google will crawl your AJAX-pages if written correctly... there is a whole bunch of articles written on this.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do both.

Have the grid load with SEO friendly anchor GET links then implement some JavaScript to convert them to AJAX calls.

People without JavaScipt (like spiders) can then still navigate around while fancy people will get the enhanced AJAX experience.

With AJAX you can alter history and make the back button work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your grids are loaded via AJAX? and you are worried that SEs won't pick them up?

What you can do to get your content indexed is to:

1. use segmented URLS like CodeIgniter and WordPress instead of query strings. SEs will (supposedly) see them as subfolders.
2. Instead of loading everything in AJAX, grid data can also be represented as tabular data. What you can do is to load the tabular format for the static page, then with JS, you can replace the table with your grid.

   say for example i want to load sports stats, `mysite.com/sports/stats` should give me tabular data when JS is off, and if i had JS, that data is replaced with the grid.

Comment: The question is whether to load grids via ajax. If using GET, url is segmented of course (i.e. ) `mysite.com/sports/stats/tennis/3/` where `tennis` and `3` are actually GET params. I'm not sure about second proposal when loading large amount of data. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: so you are asking whether to use AJAX or not? my second suggestion is using a plain page (paged ofcourse, 30 items?), to load a page. if you have JS, you load the succeeding pages using AJAX. the initial page load only give it content to SEOs (which they say operate with no AJAX). so if say i load page 3 via URL, i get a static page, but requesting the succeeding pages using pagination links, use AJAX.